# When I close the program and then rerunning it, how do I store the file info into my map?

Tags: python

```
AdressBook  = '/home/bookworm/AdressBook.txt'
contacts = {}
```

**This was my attempt at storing the file into my map, but it spits out an error. **

```
data = open(AdressBook, 'r')
for line in data.readlines():
    name, info = line.split(":")
    contacts[Name] = info
```

**I don't think that you need much else of the program, but I am fairly new at programming so I could be wrong.**

```
def write():
    Data = open(AdressBook,'a')
    for Name, many in contacts.items():
        Data.write(Name + ',' + many)
    Data.close()

def read():
    Data = open(AdressBook, 'r')
    stuff = Data.read()
    print(stuff)
    Data.close()
```

**This works, but if you have any suggestions to make it more efficient, please tell me.**

```
user = input('Would you like to acess your adress book?')
if user == 'yes' or 'yep' or 'y' or 'Yes' or 'YES!' or 'YES' or 'Yurp' or 'Yeppers' or ' 
si'or'1':
    while user != 5:
        user = input('''Select One:
Press 1 to update
Press 2 to display all contacts
Press 3 to search adress book
Press 4 to delete contacts
Press 5 to quit your adress book.''')
        if user == '1':
            name = input('Please enter the name of the contact that you would like to add.')
            contact = input('Please enter the contact information of %s.'%name)
            Name = '\n' + name
            contacts.update( {Name : contact} )
            print('')
            print('%s was added to your adress book!' %name)
            print('')
            write()
        **I made the new variable Name as to help make the file neater.**

        elif user == '2':
            print('')
            read()
            print('')

        elif user == '3':
            print('')
            name = input('What is the name of the person whose contacts you need?')
            print(contacts['\n' + name])
            print('')
```

**This and deleting contacts are the reason I need to use split and store file info into my map**

```
        elif user == '4':
            print('')
            name = input('Type in the name of the contact that you would like to delete.')
            del contacts['\n' + name]
            print('Your contact List has sucessfully deleted %s' %name)
            print('')
            write()

        elif user == '5':
            print('')
            print('Thank you for acessing your adress book!')
            exit()

else:
    exit()
```

**Here is the error that I get:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bookworm/Desktop/CTY Python/test.py", line 7, in 
    name, info = line.split(":")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)**

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to split using `:`, although when you append the `name` and `info` into the file you use `,` to separate them.

Comment: Yes, but even when I change that it spits out the smame error.

Comment: Could you print(line.split(":")) and tell me what you get.

Comment: I get the following:['\n']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bookworm/Desktop/CTY Python/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    contacts[Name] = info
NameError: name 'info' is not defined

Comment: I mean: Robert: 1 929 748382 or Robert, 1 827 8483938

Comment: Right now, Robert, 1 827 8483938

Comment: Then, in the second box of code you used in your text, in the first line of the for loop, where `name, info = line.split(":")` is read, you should change it to `name, info = line.split(",")`. That is what I meant in the answer. Try it out, please.

Comment: Still the same error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bookworm/Desktop/CTY Python/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    name, info = line.split(",")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Btw, Thanks so much for helping.

Comment: You're welcome. I tried to reproduce your situation but it seems to work just fine by me. Check it out: https://i.imgur.com/f29HldJ.png

Comment: hmmm. Did you change anything else?

Comment: Everything I have is in the screenshot.

Comment: Is everything in a single file? Could you post a comment with the full code, not in bits like in the question? Or consider sharing a link to it, on Github or another hosting website.